# How to verify OTP using Firebase in ASP.NET MVC and Javscript

Tags: javascript, asp.net-mvc, firebase

I am new to this platform and hope to learn and as well help others with the coding experience I hold. My first problem statement here is about receiving OTP using Firebase. I have registered with Firebase and they have provided me with a script to update on the page, which I have done. I have also added the required libraries from firebase into the header of the page to render. On using debugger the code does make an attempt to send an OTP but in the middle of the way it breaks an and there is no info what so ever. When I am trying to send OTP to the mobile number that I am using, the OTP is not sending. I am sure I am missing some thing very tiny in the process. Below it the flow how I have placed my code on the page

```
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/firebase/10.5.2/firebase-compat.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/firebase/10.5.2/firebase-auth.min.js"></script>

<div class="well">
    <input type="text" id="number" />
    <button id="login" class="btn btn-info" onclick="phoneAUTH()">SEND OTP</button>
</div>

<script>
    window.onload = function () {
        render();
    }

    function render() {
        window.recaptchaVerifier = new firebase.auth.RecaptchaVerifier('recaptcha-container');
    }

    function phoneAUTH() {
        var a = document.getElementById("number").value;
        var number = a;

        
        alert(a);
        debugger
        firebase.auth().signInWithPhoneNumber(number, this.window.recaptchaVerifier).then(function (confirmationResult) {
            this.window.confirmationResult = confirmationResult;
            coderesult = confirmationResult;
            console.log(coderesult);
            alert("OTP send")
        }).catch(function (error) {
            alert(error.message)
        });
    }
</script>


<script type="module">
    // Import the functions you need from the SDKs you need
    import { initializeApp } from "https://www.gstatic.com/firebasejs/10.5.2/firebase-app.js";
    import { getAnalytics } from "https://www.gstatic.com/firebasejs/10.5.2/firebase-analytics.js";
    // TODO: Add SDKs for Firebase products that you want to use
    // https://firebase.google.com/docs/web/setup#available-libraries

    // Your web app's Firebase configuration
    // For Firebase JS SDK v7.20.0 and later, measurementId is optional
    const firebaseConfig = {
        apiKey: "AIzaSyCBR07M5oy-dwiX2-xHH9LUH194fFBos7M",
        authDomain: "otplogin-ed469.firebaseapp.com",
        projectId: "otplogin-ed469",
        storageBucket: "otplogin-ed469.appspot.com",
        messagingSenderId: "1098157799928",
        appId: "1:1098157799928:web:ccc85bf671cdd6cfd43e0d",
        measurementId: "G-F1LK7MY2HZ"
    };

    // Initialize Firebase
    const app = initializeApp(firebaseConfig);
    const analytics = getAnalytics(app);
</script>
```

I have tried to google a fix for the issue with no success. There are many article on google and on Stackoverflow, but none of them could help me resolve this. Not that the articles have issue, there is some thing minor I am missing.